# Observable finally not getting fired

Tags: rxjs, angular2-http

This works:

```
this.http.get('/doesntexist1')
  .finally(() => console.log('finally1'))
  .subscribe(() => { });
```

But this doesn't:

```
const obs = this.http.get('/doesntexist2');
obs.finally(() => console.log('finally2'))
obs.subscribe(() => { });
```

Both URL produce a 404.

I run both and I only see "finally1" being displayed in the console, any idea why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is that in the second example the `.finally` is not in the same stream as the `.subscribe` since you aren't chaining them.

Your first example creates this stream:

```
get -> finally -> subscribe
```

Your second example creates two branches:

```
get -> finally
get -> subscribe
```

The finally wont be executed without a subscription after it.

If you want to build a stream then you need to chain the operators by using the result of the previous operator. It isn't like an in-place operator.

Comment: "The finally wont be executed without a subscription after it." do you know why this is?

Comment: @Luke streams don't execute when not subscribed to.